# How to get a variable from a native module in native side

Tags: android, react-native

In iOS I can get a react native module instance by calling `[self.bridge moduleForName:@"abcModule"]`, but I can't find a method like this in Android. Does anyone know about it?

Answer (score 3):

I found it!
Just call `reactContext.getNativeModule(abcModule.class)`!